# Añadir espacios en una cadena dada por teclado

Tags: java, string, substring

Estoy intentado hacer este ejercicio.

Escribir un procedimiento que, dada una cadena de entrada, devuelva la misma cadena, pero con un espacio entre cada una de sus letras. Ej: PROC('Hola qué tal?') → 'H o l a q u é t a l ?'.

```
package pracitca1;

import utilidades.Entrada;

public class Ejercicio5 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String palabra;
        System.out.print("Ingrese una palabra: ");
        palabra = Entrada.cadena();

        proc(palabra);

    }

    public static void proc(String palabra) {

        String[] almacen = palabra.split(" "); // Convierte el texto ingresado por teclado en array, ya que va
                                                // almacenar en cada posición del array una letra

        for (int i = 0; i < almacen.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(almacen[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A esto le falta especificar cuál es el problema con el código :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al usar Split en tu método estas creando un array de tamaño 3 que contienen=[hola,que,tal?] y luego  estas imprimiendo cada posición de ese nuevo arreglo creado

```
public static void proc(String palabra) {

        String[] almacen = palabra.split(" "); // Convierte el texto ingresado por teclado en array, ya que va
                                                // almacenar en cada posición del array una letra
        for (int i = 0; i < almacen.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(almacen[i]);
        }
    }
```

algo mas practico que podrías realizar es usar [replaceAll](https://guru99.es/java-string-replace-method/) el cual te permite remplazar un carácter por otro, en este caso usando una expresión regular reemplazas los espacios para juntar toda una frase como una solo palabra

```
      public static void proc(String palabra) {
        
            String almacen = palabra.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    
    //almacen ahora sera igual a holaquetal?,ahora solo debes recorrer la palabra con ayuda de un for y chartAt
    for (int i = 0; i < almacen.length(); i++) {
//ahora imprimes adicionando un espacio " "
            System.out.print(almacen.charAt(i) +" ");
            }
        }
```

[chartAt](https://guru99.es/string-charat-method-java/)